# Custom Class could not load the other classes path in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5 and doing my final year project in laravel 5. I am implementing 5 star rating system functionality using **Jrating** plugin and got stuck at 1 point. I wrote my own php code and keep it in **App/classes** directory. Now Problem is that when I call my custom file (**Rating.php**) from View (**ABC.blade.php**) using JRating plugin it went to the **Rating.php** but in this file it is not loading Model Class and my other custom class. I got the following Error.

**Fatal error: Class 'ManageRatings' not found in C:\wamp\www\laravel\fresh\app\classes\rating.php**

Below is my 3 custom files and a View File..

**(ManageRatings.php)**

```
<?php namespace App\classes;
use App\shaadi_hall_info;
use DB;

class ManageRatings{


        public static function getItems($id = null){
            if(isset($id)){

        $query = DB::table('shaadi_hall_info')->select('rating', 'total_rating','total_rates','ip_address')->where('hall_id','=','$id')->get();

            }
            else
            {
                $query = DB::table('shaadi_hall_info')->get();
            }

            return $query;
        }

        public function insertRatings($id,$rating,$total_rating,$total_rates,$ip_address){


             $query = DB::table('shaadi_hall_info')
            ->where('hall_id','=','id')
            ->update(array('rating' => 'rating', 'total_rating' => 'total_rating', 'total_rates' => 'total_rates', 'ip_address' => 'CONCAT(ip_address,",$ip_address")'));

            return $query;
        }
    }
```

**(Ratings.php)**

```
<?php namespace App\classes;

use App\classes\ManageRatings;
use App\shaadi_hall_info;
use DB;

    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['error'] = false;

   $init = new ManageRatings; 
    if($_POST)
    {
        $id = $_POST['idBox'];
        $rate = $_POST['rate'];
    }

    $ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $existingData = $init->getItems($id);


    foreach($existingData as $data)
    {
        $old_total_rating = $data['total_rating'];
        $total_rates = $data['total_rates'];
    }

    $current_rating = $old_total_rating + $rate;
    $new_total_rates = $total_rates + 1;
    $new_rating = $current_rating / $new_total_rates;

    $insert = $init->insertRatings($id,$new_rating,$current_rating,$new_total_rates,$ip_address);

    if($insert == 1)
    {
        $response['success'] = 'Success';
    }
    else
    {
        $response['error'] = 'Error';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

**(getItems.php)**

```
<?php namespace App\classes;

use App\classes\ManageRatings;
use App\shaadi_hall_info;
use DB;

    $init = new ManageRatings;
    $allItems = $init->getItems();
```

Here is my View Part where I am sending the request to **Rating.php** file..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $(".rating").jRating({
                decimalLength : 1,
                rateMax : 5, // maximal rate - integer from 0 to 9999 (or more)
                phpPath: '../App/classes/rating.php',
                onSuccess: function(){
                    alert('Your rating has been submitted');
                },
                onError: function(){
                    alert('There was a problem submitting your feedback');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I am using the correct **namespace** in each file but don't know why I am getting this weird Error. Rating System code is working fine in simple **Php** but when I convert it into **Laravel 5** I am getting this strange error. Please help me in this I got stuck in this for last 6 hours... Thanks in advance..